Calculate and transfrom the metric to the orthonormal frame
Let's suppose, the line element is like this:
$$ds^2 = -a^2(1+2\psi)d\tau^2 - 2a^2 B_idx^i d\tau + a^2(1-2\phi)(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$$
I like to get the output of the metric components from it, preferably in the matrix form:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} - a^2(1+2\psi) & -2a^2B_x & -2a^2B_y & -2a^2B_z \\ -2a^2B_x & a^2(1-2\phi) & 0 & 0 \\ -2a^2B_y & 0 & a^2(1-2\phi) & 0 \\ -2a^2B_z & 0 & 0 & a^2(1-2\phi) \end{pmatrix} $$
Then I want to compute and get the matrix form of the basis in its orthonormal frame.

Obviously the metric in orthonormal coordinates is the Identity matrix. Or do I misunderstand something?

I have updated the question. The Physics SE's answer might be useful for this context.
